# Serialize string to JSON without \0027

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization

A fairly straightforward question. I have the following code

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var test = json.Serialize("'");
```

Now, Visual Studio local variable watch shows that `test` contains a string of value `"\"\\u0027\""`. Is it possible, using build in ASP.NET to make `Serialize();` return serialized string without `\0027` format?

The desired result for `test` would be `"\"\'\""`

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the output after deserialization? it will automatically parse the special characters

Comment: No problem. `\u0027` is equal to `'`? Any other question?

Comment: There is probably an option buried in the Debug settings that controls how multi-byte characters are displayed.

Comment: Having ```'``` replaced by  ```\u0027``` is not a problem or it is depending on how you use the result of the serialization. Serializing to transmit via a Web server and then deserializing is just the most common use of serialization, not the only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the commenters mentioned, this really shouldn't matter because `\u0027` literally represents a single quote in Javascript.

However, if this bothers you, you may want to try using JSON.NET, which leaves single-quotes in encoded strings as they are.

Comment: it bothers microsoft azure for one ;]

Comment: Json.Net NuGet package do the trick. Here is its page: https://github.com/obarlik/Json.Net/wiki/Json.Net's-Home

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

`var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this expression to replace your JSON string after it's serialized. Here is a sample of my code along with a function I use when giving a json output.

```
string json = obj.ToJSON();

json = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(json);

File.WriteAllText("<DirectoryFile>.json", json);

public static string ToJSON(this object obj)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    return js.Serialize(obj);
}
```